# React router not redirects pragmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react code not redirecting.
here my code. I am using a react-router-dom. and using material-ui

```
    import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 bodycon: {
     position: 'fixed',
     left:0,
     right:0,
     bottom:0,
     top:0,
     display: 'flex'
 },
 lefthand: {
     flexBasis: '50%',
     flexGrow: 1,
     background: '#2979ff',
 },
 righthand: {
     flexBasis: '50%',
     flexGrow: 1,
     padding: '25px',
     overflow: 'scroll'
 },
 logocon: {
    background: 'url(https://i.imgur.com/pJZnNiQ.png) no-repeat',
    width: '100%',
    height: '200px',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    backgroundSize: '90px 90px',
 },
 titletext: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontSize: '22px',
    fontWeight: '300',
    textAlign: 'center',
 },
 inputcon: {
    margin: '25px auto',
    maxWidth: '350px',
 },
 formControl: {
     width: '100%',
 },
 telField: {
     width: '100%'
 },
 button: {
     width: '100%',
     marginTop: '6px'
 }
}));

export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    country: 'bd',
    tel: '',
    phonevaildity: false,
    redirect: false
  });
  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);
  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const form1 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!state.country || state.tel.length<5) {
        setState({...state, phonevaildity: 'true'})
    } else {
        axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/mu2gn')
        .then(res => {
            if(state.country === 'bd') {
                return <Redirect to="/avout"> //Nothing happens
            }
        })
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.bodycon}>
      <Hidden smDown>
        <div className={classes.lefthand}></div>
      </Hidden>
      <div className={classes.righthand}>
        <div className={classes.logocon}></div>
        <div className={classes.titletext}>Access your account</div>
        <div className={classes.inputcon}>
            <form method="post" onSubmit={form1}>
                <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                    <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="outlined-country-native-simple">
                      Country
                    </InputLabel>
                    <Select native value={state.country} onChange={handleChange('country')} input={<OutlinedInput name="Country" labelWidth={labelWidth} id="outlined-country-native-simple" />}>
                      <option value={'bd'}>Bangladesh</option>
                      <option value={'in'}>India</option>
                      <option value={'pk'}>Pakistan</option>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <TextField error={state.phonevaildity} name="tel" id="outlined-tel" label="Phone number" onChange={handleChange('tel')} onFocus={() => setState({...state, phonevaildity: false})} autoComplete="off" type="tel" className={classes.telField} margin="normal" variant="outlined" />
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" size="large" color="primary" className={classes.button}>NEXT</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my if clause, the  not working. when button clicks , a HTTP request happens, but after that no redirects are doing. please kindly help me. I am using material-ui I am in a confusion that where is the render function.

Answer (score 1):

`<Redirect />` is like a component and can be used where you've written your html/jsx. here you're returning it but its not getting into the dom / with other html. 
if you want to redirect programmably you can use the functions provided by 'react-router-dom' itself. 
but for that your component must be somehow connected with Route component so you can have access to their functions in your props.
if your component is not connected with  you can still manage to get access to there functions by wrapping your component with an HOC provided by react-router.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and wrap your component by it (export it in the end)

```
export default withRouter(Home)
```

now you can have access to their functions, simply use:

```
props.history.replace('/avout')
```

instead of using `<Redirect />` 
don't forgot to get the props where you're writing the function defination

```
const Home = function(props){}
```

About your confusion about materiel-ui component not having a render method, it is a functional component, render methods are in class components [read more about functional components here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) 
Material ui has ended the support for class components after version 4. you can still use them in earliear versions i.e 3.9.